# Create relationship between nodes having same property value in common, using one Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Beginning with Neo4j 1.9.2, and using Cypher query language, I would like to create relationships between nodes having a specific property value in common.
I have set of nodes G having a property H, without any relationship currently existing between G nodes.

In a Cypher statement, is it possible to group G nodes by H property value and create a relationship HR between each nodes becoming to same group? Knowing that each group have a size between 2 & 10 and I'm having more than 15k of such groups (15k different H values) for about 50k G nodes.

I've tried hard to manage such query without finding a correct syntax. Below is a small sample dataset:

```
create 
(G1 {name:'G1', H:'1'}),
(G2 {name:'G2', H:'1'}),
(G3 {name:'G3', H:'1'}),

(G4 {name:'G4', H:'2'}),
(G5 {name:'G5', H:'2'}),
(G6 {name:'G6', H:'2'}),
(G7 {name:'G7', H:'2'})
return * ;
```

At the end, I'd like such relationships:

```
G1-[:HR]-G2-[:HR]-G3-[:HR]-G1
```

And:

```
G4-[:HR]-G5-[:HR]-G6-[:HR]-G7-[:HR]-G4
```

In another case, I may want to update massively the relationships between nodes using/comparing some of their properties. Imagine nodes of type N and nodes of type M, with N nodes related to M with a relationship named :IS_LOCATED_ON. The order of the location can be stored as a property of N nodes (N.relativePosition being Long from 1 to MAX_POSITION), but we may need later to update the graph model such a way: make N nodes linked between themselves by a new :PRECEDES relationship, so that we can find easier and faster next node N on the given set.

I'd expect such language may allow to update massive set of nodes/relationships manipulating their properties.

- Is it not possible?
- If not, is it planned or may be it planned?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's nothing in the data you supplied to get rank, I've played with collections
to get one as follows:

```
START 
    n=node(*), n2=node(*) 
WHERE 
    HAS(n.H) AND HAS(n2.H) AND n.H = n2.H
WITH n, n2 ORDER BY n2.name
WITH n, COLLECT(n2) as others
WITH n, others, LENGTH(FILTER(x IN others : x.name < n.name)) as rank
RETURN n.name, n.H, rank ORDER BY n.H, n.name;
```

Building off of that you can then start determining relationships

```
START 
    n=node(*), n2=node(*) 
WHERE 
    HAS(n.H) AND HAS(n2.H) AND n.H = n2.H
WITH n, n2 ORDER BY n2.name
WITH n, COLLECT(n2) as others
WITH n, others, LENGTH(FILTER(x IN others : x.name < n.name)) as rank
WITH n, others, rank, COALESCE(
    HEAD(FILTER(x IN others : x.name > n.name)),
    HEAD(others)
    ) as next
RETURN n.name, n.H, rank, next ORDER BY n.H, n.name;
```

Finally ( and slightly more condensed )

```
START 
    n=node(*), n2=node(*) 
WHERE 
    HAS(n.H) AND HAS(n2.H) AND n.H = n2.H
WITH n, n2 ORDER BY n2.name
WITH n, COLLECT(n2) as others
WITH n, others, COALESCE(
    HEAD(FILTER(x IN others : x.name > n.name)),
    HEAD(others)
    ) as next
CREATE n-[:HR]->next
RETURN n, next;
```

Comment: Hello @LameCoder, thanks for your answer. This query is not really straighforward, but I understand the logic.

Since I don't need to create HR self relationship on a node, we can add another restriction (g1<>g2), which allows to delete COALESCE statement since we don't need anymore to order g2 by name: 

START 
    g1=node(*), g2=node(*) 
WHERE 
    HAS(g1.H) AND HAS(g2.H) AND g1.H = g2.H AND g1 <> g2
WITH g1, COLLECT(g2) as others
WITH g1, HEAD(others) as next
CREATE g1-[:HR]->next
RETURN g1, next;

Comment: (...continues...)
The query is currently running, but it is really really long to execute. Your query ran in more than 8 hours (30052902 ms) and created 47412 relationships, as I excepted on my dataset.

It seems that the 2 nodes START clause is a bad approach, even when I use index to lookup g1 and g2.

The updated query above is currently running, i'll see the results later if it improves performances, but it's running since several hours such approach can't be a good solution. Using Java code took few seconds to load data and create relationships.

Anyway thanks for your tips @LameCoder. ;)

Comment: @RaphaelF. It's not an ideal solution. I just like trying to see what we can make Cypher do, it's a pretty fun puzzle.  It's problems like this that make me wish there were stored procedures.

Comment: Indeed, I agree that Cypher is not currently mature for data management, I don't know why having 2 start points is so heavy since each start point alone is very fast. Even when I return only a count on each start point it take much time. Seems there is some optimization to do concerning multi lookup.
However, I'm not sure stored procedure may improve performances in this case since the query is simple to parse, the pitfall seems to concern multi start lookup.

Comment: If feature of [issue #82](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/389) was implemented, I think we may be able to write such query:

    START g1=node()
    WHERE HAS(g1.H)
    WITH g1
    START g2=node()
    MATCH g1-[hr?:HR]->g2
    WHERE g1 <> g2
    AND HAS(g2.H) 
    AND g2.H = g1.H
    AND hr is null # avoid to create twice HR between two same nodes
    WITH g1, COLLECT(g2) as others 
    WITH g1, HEAD(others) as next 
    CREATE UNIQUE g1-[:HR]->next 
    RETURN g1, next;

I think this would be like writing a FOR loop using the first START statement, here g1.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like that, maybe indicate direction in your relationships:

```
CREATE 
  (G1 { name:'G1', H:'1' }),
  (G2 { name:'G2', H:'1' }),
  (G3 { name:'G3', H:'1' }),
  (G4 { name:'G4', H:'2' }),
  (G5 { name:'G5', H:'2' }),
  (G6 { name:'G6', H:'2' }),
  (G7 { name:'G7', H:'2' }), 
  G1-[:HR]->G2-[:HR]->G3-[:HR]->G1, 
  G4-[:HR]->G5-[:HR]->G6-[:HR]->G7-[:HR]->G1
```

See http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ujns0x for an example.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the graph is already created with all the nodes. I can't hard code the relationships for each 45k node. I'd like to create them later using Cypher. I think I could do using Java language but I'm wondering here about Cypher capabilities.