# neo4j cypher Error: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Unknown identifier `b` after index created

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a similar problem as in [Create relationship between nodes having same property value in common, using one Cypher query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289949/create-relationship-between-nodes-having-same-property-value-in-common-using-on) in my local neo4j environment giving me strange behaviour (I test this in both M06 and RC1). Basically the problem is if I don't create the index on name, then the query took forever in my local environment. But after I create the index then I get the error as you see above.

```
CREATE (n1:Node { id:'n1', name:'n' }) 
CREATE (n2:Node { id:'n2', name:'n' }) 
CREATE (n3:Node { id:'n3', name:'n' }) 
CREATE (g1:Node { id:'g1', name:'g' }) 
CREATE (g2:Node { id:'g2', name:'g' }) 
CREATE (g3:Node { id:'g3', name:'g' })
```

the first query seems to be ok
    MATCH (a:Node),(b:Node) 
    WHERE a.name=b.name and a<>b
    RETURN a,b

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Node(name)
```

after the index created, run the query again, and error.
    MATCH (a:Node),(b:Node) 
    WHERE a.name=b.name and a<>b
    RETURN a,b

http://console.neo4j.org/r/zebo0i

Comment: I'd file this in github issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.  It's a bug, for now you can work around it with this:

```
match (a:Node)-[:In]->(t:Ticket)<-[:In]-(b)
using scan a:Node
where a.name=b.name 
return a,t,b
```